# List of elements on same diagonal

Tags: algorithm, element, counting, diagonal

Consider a given nxn matrix. Input is n
You are then given (row,col) of those elements that exist in the matrix as a list of coordinates. Say k such elements
Total elements n^2, k elements are populated.
Max(k)=n^2, every element is populated.

Q. Find number and list of elements that are on the same diagonal.

## 1.

One approach is to compare each element row,col difference  absolute value of every other element. 2 elements are on the same diagonal if:
Row2-Row1 == Col2-Col1 or
Row2-Row1 == -(Col2-Col1)

If there are k elements given we have k(k-1) comparisons, one for positive difference  and one for negative difference (absolute functions too will do the same internally, compare positive and negative difference, so each is compared twice)

Total checks : k(k-1)

## 2.

We simply iterate along each diagonal. If we find 2 elements or more we push all those found in a list.
Each element is visited twice, once along the -1 slope diagonal and other along the +1 slope diagonal.

Total checks: 2n^2

Consider n=5 and k=8
That is 25 slots in the grid with 8 slots populated

In this case #2 has 50 checks while #1 has 56 checks.

Likewise n=10, k=15

We have #1 giving 210 checks and #2 giving 200 checks.

So is algorithm #2 not generally better than #1

Unless the matrix is sparsely populated, but we don't know that upfront, k could be small or large. We have to choose 1 method.

Which method #1 or #2 seems like a better choice for this problem?

Feel free to just stick to count and forget the list, if it suites you.

Or maybe I missed something or a better method

PS: if 2,1 and 3,2 and 1,2 are the elements the count should be 3. Don't count the same element twice. There could be a 5,1 and 6,2 too, so its essentially 2,1 3,2 1,2 5,1 6,2 total 5 elements

Comment: Perhaps you want to notice that `row2-row1==col2-col1` IFF `row1-col1==row2-col2`.

Comment: Or you could say sum of row+col or difference of row-col is same if elements are on same diagonal.Still it's 2 comparisons if I do it over the list of k

Answer (score 1):

Numerate diagonals with any convenient method (there are 4n-2 diagonals if we count for 1-length ones).

Every item belongs to two diagonals. Just add these diagonals ID's into hash map with counter=1 or increment counter if map entry exists.

If k is comparable with n or larger, then simple array indexed by diagonal number would be better than map.

**P.S.** Just noticed `and list of elements`:
Map entry also should contain a list of coordinates.

In the end find map entry with the largest counter end extract list of item coordinates.

Time and space complexity is O(k) (space O(n) for case of array)

For example, n=4, and we numerate / diagonals (map F) from the left top corner, \ diagonals (map B) from the right top corner. There are 7 possible diagonals for every direction.

Example: we add 5 points with coordinates (row, column). Diagonal F(0) intersects digit 1, diagonal B(2) intersects digit 0 (my labeling was broken)

[image]

```
(0, 0) increments F(0) and B(3)
(2, 2) increments F(4) and B(3)
(1, 2) increments F(3) and B(2)
(3, 1) increments F(4) and B(5)
(1, 3) increments F(4) and B(1)
```

After all: we have counter>=2 for diagonals F(4) and B(3)

**Edit:**  To get unique items:

Push all diagonal items into hash map (ignoring duplicate). Complexity is O(k') where k' is number of diagonal items

Or another variant: sort merged list, then extracting duplicates is trivial. Complexity is O(k'*log(k'))

Comment: It's still every element twice?

Comment: Every element generate two diagonal entries in map.

Comment: For each element we compute sum and difference. We can have total 2n-1 sums and 2n-1 differences . We increment count of array[thiselementsum] by one while checking k elements. Like wise for difference. Total k checks here, and then we check if each of array of size 4n-2 is greater than 1, we can have repeat elements here by the way. It doesn't give me count of elements that are on a diagonal

Comment: Perhaps you did not understand proposed approach. Will make an example

Comment: Not sure if one can avoid an array_unique at the end of it. Even if we store the elements.

Comment: I dont want max diagonal, i want all elements that can form a diagonal or count(elements) that can form a diagonal

Comment: So get lists for all diagonals with `counter>=2`

Comment: But no repetitions. That unique array time cost also has to be taken. In my method I simply set element to 2 if it's already taken and leave it at 1 if not taken. That helps me push only unique elements

Comment: Your description of building S and D is right. About unique- look at my edit.

Comment: If k is close to n then it is expensive

Comment: You must treat all k items, there is no way to miss part of input, so O(k) complexity is minimal possible

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @MBo,

In your example there are 4 elements that form a diagonal, not 3 
ie. - (0,0) (1,3) (2,2) (1,3)

Let me rewrite my understanding
Let us assume we can have negative array indices for easier discussion, we can always bump up -n to 0 and n to 2n-1 in the code.

We define 2 arrays Sum and Diff

Sum can vary from 2 to 2n  .. / diagonal, (2n-1 values)

Diff can be between -n and n (2n-1 values)  inclusive 0 ,.... \ diagonal

```
foreach ele in k
elesum=elerow+elecol
elediff=elerow-elecol
push Sum[elesum] , (elerow,elecol)
push Diff[elediff],  (elerow,elecol)
next ele
```

This has k elements in each array,k iterations

We then do:

```
foreach S in Sum
if count S > 2 push final_list,S
Next S
```

This has max 2n-1 iterations

```
foreach D in Diff
if count D > 2 push final_list,D
Next D
```

This also has max 2n-1 iterations.

We now have a final_list=merge(S,D) with row,col of all elements in a diagonal (non unique)
We now have to unique final_list.

Only for the comparison part:

kmax=n^2

Total max n^2+4n-2 iterations for comparison.

The uniquenes cost is perhaps not the same, I can do a in_array check everytime I push a new element by the diagonal scan approach. How do I do it here because I need to note that while an element may exist in sum array, it may not exist (so far) in diff array but could have a future match.

So I have to retain all Sums and Diffs of each element to start with.

**In my case I can simply set val(row,col)=2 if the element is already populated in the final_list array. Then when scanning the other sloped diagonal I simply check first if that element is >0, and then if it is >1 , if not I push it on the final_list and set it to 2.** You can do the same at the S iteration but in the D iteration each element will have to be compared against the existing list too.

If it was an assembler code I would set it to -1 instead of 2 and do a cmp with 0 and JL,JG and JE would suffice.

So if all elements are populated both Sum and Diff will contain n^2 elements when I merge them to do an array_unique.

In my diagonal scan, I simply need to check if element is in list before I push.
Can you explain that bit in this case?

Is my understanding of your approach correct?